# creating a CTE to filter previous CTE populaiton down. How to find new diagnosis of certain ICD 10 code?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

The first CTE grabs all patients with the diagnosis codes for substance abuse,

The second CTE should filter this down to only NEW patients. Meaning of the people in the first CTE, which of these people have now been diagnosed with the 2 codes before.

The 3rd CTE grabs all information about the person, locations, date, and age.

**In need of figuring out the logic for the 2nd CTE: from diag ... only people who haven't been diagnosed before (ie. new/initial diagnosis)**

```
with diag as (
select distinct d.person_id
, d.encntr_id
, d.diagnosis_id
, d.nomenclature_id
, d.diag_dt_tm
, d.diag_prsnl_name
, d.diagnosis_display
, cv.display as Source_Vocabulary 
, nm.source_identifier as ICD_10_Code
, nm.source_string as ICD_10_Diagnosis
, nm.concept_cki 
from wny_prod.diagnosis d 
inner join (select * from nomenclature
        where source_vocabulary_cd in (151782752, 151782747) --ICD 10 CM and PCS
        and (source_identifier ilike 'F10.10' or source_identifier ilike 'F19.10')) nm on d.nomenclature_id = nm.nomenclature_id
left join code_value cv on nm.source_vocabulary_cd = cv.code_value 
)

diag_final as (
select * 
from diag
--?
)

select distinct ea.FIN
, dem.patient_name
, dem.dob
, age_in_years(e.beg_effective_dt_tm::date, dem.dob) as Age_at_Encounter
, amb.location_name
, e.beg_effective_dt_tm
, diag.Source_Vocabulary 
, diag.ICD_10_Code
, diag.ICD_10_Diagnosis
from (select * from encounter where year(beg_effective_dt_tm) = 2022) e 
left join (select distinct encntr_id, alias as FIN from encntr_alias where encntr_alias_type_cd = 844) ea on e.encntr_id = ea.encntr_id
inner join diag on e.encntr_id = diag.encntr_id
inner join (select distinct * from DEMOGRAPHICS where mrn_rownum = 1 and phone_rownum = 1 and address_rownum = 1) dem on e.person_id = dem.person_id
inner join locations_amb amb on amb.loc_facility_cd = e.loc_facility_cd
where age_in_years(e.beg_effective_dt_tm::date, dem.dob) > 13
```

Comment: Create a CTE with the min(date) of each patient with that dx_code list. Build off that.

Comment: Do you only want patients who have been diagnosed once or do you want the first diagnosis even if there have been subsequent diagnoses for that patient?

Comment: I would like to see the initial diagnosis/ new diagnosis only. For some patients there may be multiple diagnoses but only initial diagnosis.

Comment: Use a windows function to create a row number for each group of patient records (you can probably do this in the first CTE, you don't need a second one) and then filter where row number = 1

Comment: this originally how I went about this. I created a row num based on the diagnosis dt tm where = 1. Although, I was told this cannot be used since the date/time might not properly indicate if this was the actual first ever diagnosis. Im unsure if there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: After testing, only 1 patient comes up from this method. Under 300 patients is expected.

Comment: If the diagnosis dt tm does not accurately reflect which was the first diagnosis then what are the business rules/logic that need to be applied that will correctly identify the first diagnosis?

Comment: Unfortunatly, this is unknown. The logic I think makes sense is: of the main population of all people diagnosed, who has never had that diagnosis before?

Comment: In the second cte it would be something like this: where person_id is not in (hasn’t ever been diagnosed before with the two ICD10 codes)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the "most recent diagnostic" or "first diagnostic" for a person, then row_number, first_value, or last_value can help.

But you said you want people how have not had "prior".

The simple way to find people with "no prior" is to only keep rows with count of 1

```
with entities_with_critia_we_care_about_aka_diag(person_id, diagnosis_id, diag_dt_tm) as (
    select * from values
    -- 1 has match exactly a year ago
    (1, 2001, '2023-08-04 12:01:02'::timestamp),
    (1, 1001, '2021-08-04 12:01:02'::timestamp),
    -- 2 is only ever matched once
    (2, 2002, '2023-08-04 12:01:02'::timestamp),

    -- 3 has two diags on the same day, can this happen?
    (3, 2002, '2023-08-04 12:01:02'::timestamp),
    (3, 2003, '2023-08-04 12:01:02'::timestamp)
    
)
select 
    person_id
    ,diagnosis_id
    ,diag_dt_tm
    ,count(*) over (partition by person_id) as diag_count
from entities_with_critia_we_care_about_aka_diag
```

so here the first CTE is your "first CTE" but just with details that seem meaningful to me, to answer the SQL question.

[image]

now for person 1 & 2 count seems a good test, but do you get people "processed" within windows of time, that really count as "first" aka can you get many rows like person 3?

Then mentioned in the comments, `daig_dt_tm` does not seem to be correct as you only get 1 row.

Perhaps if diagnosis_id is from a trusted incremental source (like a database) that could be used instead of time.